# creating links `next/prev` inside JQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a photo thumb list:

```
<div>
 <a href="#" class="open-dialog" id="17"><img src=/upl/thumb_100_100_2144473683ec519.jpg /></a>
</div>

<div>
 <a href="#" class="open-dialog" id="18"><img src=/upl/thumb_100_100_23688dddd187dc7.jpg /></a>
</div>

<div>
 <a href="#" class="open-dialog" id="19"><img src=/upl/thumb_100_100_684889213b56545.jpg /></a>
</div>

<div id='photo-content'></div>
```

after clicking on thumb I get JQuery UI dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.open-dialog').live('click', function() {

      var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $("#photo-content").load('/photo/' + id).dialog({ //loads php file with full size photo and other content

          width: '700px',
          resizable: false,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              'Close': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
          },

        }); 
    });

 });
```

it loads successfully with all data I need.

So now I want to have `next/prev` links inside loaded dialog. Dialog should be closed and reloaded with new content after clicking `next`. Or maybee not closed, just reloaded...this is where I'm stuck.

html:

```
...
<a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
...
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.next').live('click', function() {
   $('#photo-content').dialog('close');
   var next_id = <?=$next_photo?>;

     $("#photo-content").load('/photo/' + next_id).dialog({

          width: '700px',
          resizable: false,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              'Close': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
          }); 
      });

 });
```

I've tried this way, but after every click on `next` I get more and more opened dialogs.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a working page for us to look at? http://jsfiddle.net is a good way to quickly share this kind of code. Your problem should be pretty simple to fix once we've got that.

Comment: It seems like your life would be a lot easier if you just used Colorbox http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/.  It includes support for image grouping/automatic next and prev arrows.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I've tried other JQuery lightboxes before, but not successfully (because I wanted to load from url not only photo, but much more content with other dialogs inside). So I decided to use JQuery UI dialog. But it really was easier to do that with Colorbox. Thanks again, especially T Nguyen.